# JIT error in Java

Tags: java, websphere, jit

The following Java code:

```
private void a(Object paramObject) throws IOException {
    if ((paramObject instanceof Socket)) {
        this.o = ((Socket)paramObject).getOutputStream();
        this.i = ((Socket)paramObject).getInputStream();
    } else {
        this.o = new FileOutputStream(((RandomAccessFile)paramObject).getFD());
        this.i = new BufferedInputStream(
            new FileInputStream(((RandomAccessFile)paramObject).getFD()), 65536);
    }
}
```

sporadically produces the following exception, but only when run in the IBM Java VM in WebSphere:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.net.Socket incompatible with java.io.RandomAccessFile
```

No other Java VM has this problem. I think it must be due to a JIT error in the IBM Java VM. The parameter can only be a `java.net.Socket` or a `java.io.RandomAccessFile`. The object is created in the same class. It cannot be a `ClassLoader` problem either.

How should I modify my code to avoid this problem?

Comment: Could it possibly be that there are multiple different Socket classes available in the IBM JVM that you are importing?

Comment: By the way: report this effect to IBM, file a bug. They *might* just fix it.

Comment: @Bringer128: I thought of this as well, but it's very unlikely for a `java.*` class (you'd have to jump through some serious hoops to re-define that).

Comment: @Bringer128 The instance of the socket was create in the same class with new. I have no idea how 2 methods of the same class can work with 2 different classes of the same name.

Comment: @Joachim Sauer There is a bug report. But IBM can not reproduce it currently. Else if it is reprodible it can take a long time to fix.

Answer (score 3):

If it is indeed a JIT error (and frankly I don't see any other reason for this exception at this place), then it's **very hard** to tell exactly *what* change might prevent this.

A *tiny* change (swapping the if-blocks and negating the check) *might* help, but it can equally well be that there's almost nothing you can do here.

The *safest* bet is probably to disable JIT-compilation of this method altogether. Unfortunately the process of doing that varies from JVM to JVM (and might not be supported on some JVMs at all!).

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Joachim Sauer that the code looks fine.

You may refactor the code into two methods, one for the `Socket` and one for the `RandomAccessFile`. This might help because internally the parameter variable might have the type information attached to it.

Another thing you could do is this:

```
if (paramObject instanceof Socket) {
  handleSocket((Socket) paramObject);
} else if (paramObject instanceof RandomAccessFile) {
  handleRandomAccessFile((RandomAccessFile) paramObject);
} else {
  throw new IllegalStateException(paramObject.getClass() + paramObject.getClass().getClassLoader());
  // plus more information that you might need.
}
```